# Specify outbound IP in PDO connection

Tags: php, pdo

I need to do a remote mysql connection from a server to another, using a standard PDO connection:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DATABASE_HOST . ';dbname=' . DATABASE_NAME . ';charset=utf8mb4', DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASSWORD, [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
]);
```

The problem is that this server has many IPs attached, both IPv4 and IPv6, and to avoid this error:

> Host '2001:...' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server in ...

I'd need to create many users in the target host, one for each IP... (or allow connections from any IP, which is unsafe)

Is it possible to specify which IP to use?
For example with curl I can do that with:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, '1.2.3.4');
```

But I didn't find any similar option for PDO.

Comment: AFAIK no, you can't. Why not just whitelist all the IPs on the mysql side?

Comment: **Do not do this**, but I think you could [forward a socket on](https://serverfault.com/a/753733) and "somehow" in doing so bind it to a specific local interface for egress, and then specify that socket in your connection string instead of a host. This totally sounds like something that is fragile and will easily break, but I was curious if it could be done, too.

Comment: Since MySQL 8.0.23 CIDR notation is allowed, so I can do `GRANT ... TO 'user'@'2001:...::/64' IDENTIFIED BY ...` to allow the whole block, and set the host to an ipv6 address to force ipv6 (but it should be always preferred over ipv4). Otherwise I think it would be simpler to make an API that calls the remote machine in case of failure, to edit the user with the new ip...